# Force Canonical to use HTTPS

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, view-helpers, zend-view

I want my customer section to be https, e.g. registration, login, personal details, order details, etc. I have set up my route to include the https scheme (I can access the customer section via https) but I cannot force my links to use https:

```
<a class="register" href="<?php echo $this->url('customer/default', array('controller' => 'registration', 'action' => 'index'), array('scheme' => 'https', 'force_canonical' => true,)); ?>">Register</a>
```

What I get: `http://myproject.dev/customer/registration`

What I want: `https://myproject.dev/customer/registration`

It appears to be using the current scheme - so if I'm on http then the url is http, if I'm on https then the url is https.

How do I force `$this->url` to use the `https` scheme all the time?

```
'router' => array(
  'routes' => array(
    'customer' => array(
      'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
      'options' => array(
        'route' => '/customer',
        'scheme' => 'https',
        'defaults' => array(
          '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Customer\Controller',
          'https' => true,
          'controller' => 'Index',
          'action' => 'index',
        ),
      ),
      'child_routes' => array(
        'default' => array(
          'type' => 'Segment',
          'options' => array(
            'route' => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
            'scheme' => 'https',
            'constraints' => array(
              'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
              'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
            ),
            'defaults' => array(
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

#### [edit]

`myproject.dev` is my local machine where I've changed my hosts a vhosts file. I have set up my vhosts file to accept ssl and that's not the issue.

I've changed the route type to `Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Scheme` and added the scheme option but that generates the following url: `https://myproject.dev:80/registration` which generates an `SSL connection error` as it's trying to connect to port 80!

When I change the `child_routes` `type` to `scheme` the url generated is: `https://myproject.dev:80/customer`

#### [edit]

As a stop-gap solution I am doing a htaccess redirect if the user is trying to access the customer section on a non-secure scheme:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/customer/?.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I do not like this approach as it should not be necessary!

#### [edit]

While I want my customer section to be https, I do not want the rest of the site to be.

Comment: You have two options: 1) redirect using Apache, or 2) redirect using PHP. But I'd first ask why you only want part of your site HTTPS. It's kinder to your users to simply make the entire site secure.

Answer (score 5):

> use Zend\Uri\UriFactory;

add the following code on top of your action or make a method inside a plugin.

```
$uri = $this->getRequest()->getUri();
        $uri = (string) $uri;
        $url = UriFactory::factory($uri);
        $http = 'http';
        $http_current = $url->getScheme();
        if($http == $http_current){
            $url->setScheme('https');
            return $this->redirect()->toUrl($url);
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Can you please add this 2 lines in your .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^myproject\.
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

It will run on https protocol.

Comment: I don't want to run the whole website on https, just the customer section. At the moment I am doing a rewrite rule similar to the above but still think this should be handled in the application logic.

Answer (score 3):

i believe, such automatic redirection should be done on HTTP-daemon level for all URL's starting with /customer. all popular HTTP-servers like Apache, Nginx, or Lighttpd allow such configs. it's not good to bother business logic about network security, imo.

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of the ServerUrl and URL view helpers to construct your URL's, EG:

```
<?php
$this->getHelper('ServerUrl')->setScheme('https')
?>
<a href="<?php echo $this->serverUrl($this->url('customer/default', array('controller' => 'registration', 'action' => 'index'), array('force_canonical' => true,))); ?>">Link Caption</a>
```

This will force the link to be fully qualified instead of relative and will force the scheme to be https without causing issues with the port being specified wrong.

Comment: I have tried this and am getting an exception that the helper cannot load ServerUrl. Do I need to include it as a dependency? Being a View Helper I didn't think I would need to...